# BMI Calculator not printing results

Tags: java

As part of my CS studies we are starting to learn java and I wanted to do a little side project to try to get better at Java than I am.

So far it isn't working as it should.

I have written this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BodyWeightCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double weight;
    double height;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What's your height in meters?");
    height = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("What's your weight in kilograms?");
    weight = input.nextDouble();

    double bmi = ((weight / height) / height);

    System.out.printf("Your BMI is " + bmi);

    if (bmi < 18.5)
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are underweight.");
    else if (bmi <= 18.5 & bmi > 24.9)
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are at a normal weight.");
    else if (bmi < 25 & bmi > 29.9)
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are overweight");
    else if (bmi > 30) {
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are extremely overweight");
    }
}
}
```

This programs asks the user to input his/her weight and height, and then it outputs the BMI of the user and whether he/she is of normal weight, or underweight, etc.

The program only outputs the BMI ignoring all the `if-else` statements.

Anything wrong with this?

Comment: Check your `if` conditions. `bmi <= 18.5 & bmi > 24.9` is never going to be true.

Comment: And use `&&` (logical and) instead of `&` (bitwise and).

Comment: It's up to the input you're testing it with. You might be finding an scenario where your conditions do not cover that (it returns for my bmi, heh). Also, check the other comments.

Comment: first of all your formula is wrong... check this formula http://www.epic4health.com/bmiformula.html

Comment: Thank you so much! That seemed to do the trick!

Comment: @Kayaman At least the hint to use `&&` is correct, but your explanation is obviously incorrect. `&&` and `&` are both logicals "and" if the both operands are of type `boolean`, which they are. `&&` is just a short-circuit version of `&` ([JLS §15.22.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2))

Comment: @Tom Did you read what you linked? It says `...bitwise operator expression`. Who's obviously incorrect now?

Comment: I like how this "side project" also happens to be one of the most common homework assignments ever handed out in programming.

Comment: @Tom The `&&` is apparently named the "conditional and", but I'm not the first to call it the "logical", and that wasn't even the issue.

Comment: @Kayaman *"Who's obviously incorrect now?"* We both are. I also named it incorrectly. But that doesn't fix the incomplete explanation why OP should prefer `&&` over `&`. *"and that wasn't even the issue"* not in OPs question, yes, but also didn't assert that ;P.

Comment: @Tom Well congratulations. I hope you feel you've achieved something great with your comments.

Comment: @Kayaman Salty?

Comment: @Tom There's enough to tolerate with the people asking the questions. No need for the extra people with wrong answers/comments and stupid comments that seem to have become popular as of late. It certainly doesn't raise the quality of the site.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in the set of `if-else` statements, it should cover the whole ranges. And you should use the `boolean` operator '&&' rather than using the `bitwise-operator` '&'.

```
 if (bmi < 18.5)
    System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are underweight.");
else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9)
    System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are at a normal weight.");
else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29.9)
    System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are overweight");
else if (bmi >= 30.) {
    System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are extremely overweight"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statements do not seem to cover the ranges that you are intending. Further, you should be using "&&" for "and" rather than "&", which is a bit-wise "and". You should also get in the habit of always using braces for if statement blocks, even if the block is one line.

You should rewrite your statements like so:

```
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are underweight.");
    }
    else if (18.5 <= bmi && bmi < 25.0) {
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are at a normal weight.");
    }
    else if (25.0 <= bmi && bmi < 30.0) {
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are overweight");
    }
    else if (30.0 <= bmi) {
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", you are extremely overweight");
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Should not be reached. BMI=" + bmi);
    }
```

Comment: *"Further, you should be using "&&" for "and" rather than "&", which is a bit-wise "and""* You shouldn't copy incorrect comments into your answer ;P.

Comment: @Tom: I didn't copy anyone's comments. I'm using my common sense from 15+ years of Java software engineering. If you use bit-wise "&" in an if-statement then you should really be operating at the bit level. If you are using & in place of && everywhere, then you are just going to confuse yourself, your software testers, and whoever inherits your code.

Comment: *"If you are using & in place of && everywhere, then you are just going to confuse yourself, your software testers, and whoever inherits your code."* Then they should search a different job. `&&` does the same as `&`, it is just short-circuited. It can result in issues, like in `x == null | x.isEmpty()`, but confusing? Come on.